# Apache2 redirection results in wrong URL

Tags: url, redirect, apache2

Two domains are directed to my single ip address. In the LAN, I have two Pi Apache servers. The router redirects port 80 traffic to 192.168.1.16. There, sites-available redirects domain2.com traffic to 192.168.1.11.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.domain1.com
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.domain2.com
        Redirect Permanent "/" "http://192.168.1.11/"
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My problem is that users accessing domain2.com are successfully redirected but see the URL as 192.168.1.11/blah.php, but I want them to see domain2.com/blah.php.

On 192.168.1.16, I've created a hosts entry "192.168.1.11   domain2.com", but if I change the domain2 redirection in sites-available to

```
Redirect Permanent "/" "http://domain2.com/"
```

the redirection isn't successful and domain2.com/blah.php doesn't load. "This site can’t provide a secure connection www.domain2 sent an invalid response".

How can I ensure that the users see the URL as "domain2.com" not "192.168.1.11"?